# I can't store data with electron and react

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have an application that will be on PC and Web. So I created two ways to store data. For the Web application with Firebase (in Cloud) and for the Desktop application (Windows or Linux) I would store the data directly on the machine.

But I have a problem when I want to use ipcRenderer with my react it doesn't work

I specify that I do not use Webpack.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "concurrently": "^7.4.0",
    "cowsay": "^1.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^21.1.1",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-store": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-use-draggable-scroll": "^0.4.7",
    "regexp": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "react-build": "react-scripts build",
    "react-test": "react-scripts test",
    "react-eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-builder": "electron-builder",
    "build": "npm run react-build && npm run electron-build",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron . --no-sandbox\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

electron.js

```
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");
const { FETCH_DATA_FROM_STORAGE, PUSH_DATA_TO_STORAGE } = require("../src/utils/Constants");

const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const ipcMain = electron.ipcMain;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const Store = require('electron-store');

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1080,
        height: 720,
    })

    win.loadURL(
        isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : "file://" + path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")
    )
}

let store = new Store();
ipcMain.on('FETCH_DATA_FROM_STORAGE', (event, arg) => {
    console.log('store', store.get('contests'));
});

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
})
```

ConstestHandlerApp.js

```
import { auth, firestore } from "../firebase/firebase-config";
import { Tools } from '../utils/Tools';
import { AbstractContestHandler } from "./AbstractContestHandler.ts";
import { FETCH_DATA_FROM_STORAGE, PUSH_DATA_TO_STORAGE } from "../utils/Constants";

const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

export class ContestHandlerApp extends AbstractContestHandler {

    createContest(contest) {
    }

    deleteContest(uid: string) {

    }

    updateContest(contest) {

    }

    getContest(uid: string) {
        return null;
    }

    getContests() {
        window.Electron.ipcRenderer.send(FETCH_DATA_FROM_STORAGE, "contests")
        return [];
    }
}
```

ERROR :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/username/Desktop/NextPetanque/app/node_modules/electron'


ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 2:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/username/Desktop/NextPetanque/app/node_modules/electron'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

Comment: You do use webpack, since its what `create-react-app` uses internally. You are trying, therefore, to bundle code meant for node (the code in electron.js is executed on the node side of electron, not within its nested browser) with a bundler that bundles code meant for the browser. I suggest googling" create react app electron". You will find a lot of guides on how to set it up such that you run both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the only problem is that I have already done it before I tried to find solutions but I spent all day there that's why I posted on stackoverflow .

Comment: Yeh, it might have kind of accidentally worked before. Webpack use to polyfill them but on later versions it does not. Generally, you don't want to compiled the node code in the browser bundler even if you find hacky ways around -- so the root cause is most likely related to the overall approach of trying to do that.

Comment: So what would be the solution? I am currently trying to make another application with https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate

But now I have another problem with firebase ☠️☠️

Comment: It'd be to essentially run `electron`s own CLI concurrent to `create-react-app`. This way, electron executes the node code directly with no bundling (you don't need that on back end) and `create-react-app` only deals with the client code. https://mmazzarolo.com/blog/2021-08-12-building-an-electron-application-using-create-react-app/ is the most accurate guide I've seen.

Comment: Note one key element, that might even be possible now, is `electron.js` lives in `public` which webpack wont try to compile.